# Adding featured image to a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress blog  around a 100 posts doesn't have any images associated with them except featured images! So I would like to add a snippet to the function.php or something like that, so that whenever a post is loaded the featured image will get inserted to the post where I want it.

Can somebody please help to achieve this?

Comment: "Where I want it": and where's that?

Comment: So you want to get the post thumbnail? Check out the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: @brasofilo I would like to fetch the image which is the featured image and post it in the post content itself, at the beginning.

Comment: Follow @Sven link and try something. Right now, you're just asking for code without showing [research efforts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).